# Why does rm not work in my Makefile? Using cygwin and git

Tags: cygwin

I have cygwin and git installed on Windows 7 (32-bit). Trying to execute a Makefile. When I just use `make` it works.
But when I add `rm` into my Makefile, in `fclean`, for example, that happens:

`C:\Users\SSS\libft>make fclean
rm -f *.o
      3 [main] rm (324) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\rm.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x612C3410/0x612BF410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
make: *** [Makefile:25: clean] Segmentation fault`

Rebooting didn't help.

Comment: It seems you have 2 cygwin1.dll around. How are you running cygwin ?

Comment: I only have one cygwin1.dll, I checked

Comment: `C:\Users\SSS\libft` is not a Cygwin path, so how are you running make and where it is installed ?

Comment: It looks you have a Windows install of git on your system under `C:\Program Files\Git` and it's on your `PATH` before your Cygwin install.  You should probably fix your `PATH` to make sure that when you're using Cygwin executables, the Cygwin native binaries `/usr/bin:/bin` etc. are first on your `PATH`.

Comment: thanks! it works now